# TortoiseSVN not asking for login credentials

Tags: apache, svn, repository, apache2, tortoisesvn

I've set multiple repositories hosted on an Apache2 Server on my Raspberry Pi 3, created by the standard svn program.

I've created a svn_access_control file as shown below:

```
[/]
* = r

[repo1:/]
Niko = rw
* =
```

I've also created multiple users using the following command:

```
htpasswd -m /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd USERNAME
```

My dav_svn.conf has the following lines written in it:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /home/pi/repos
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repo"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/svn_access_control
  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
 </Location>
```

Yet, when I want to access repo1 via ToirtoiseSVN on a Windows 8.1 Machine, I am not prompted with a login dialog. It just skips to the "Access forbidden" message.

```
Access to '/svn/repo1' forbidden
```

**The Authentification Data is already cleared in the Client.**

What settings do I have to change in order for TortoiseSVN to prompt me to log in?

Comment: What do you mean by "The Authentification Data is already cleared in the Client." ? Did you go to menu `TortoiseSVN => Settings => Saved Data => Authentication data` and press `Clear all` button ?

Comment: @LaurentH. Yes, as suggested by other answers to this topic on different threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using the `<LimitExcept>` directive?
you should just state `require valid-user`.

Explanation:

The LimitExcept tells the server you need authorization only for "write" access, so Apache won't ask the client for it for read access (SVN read access is composed of WEBDAV the following operations: GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT - Just the operations you told apache you do not need a limit for..).

So SVN does not send user information to server(server did not request them) and then SVN module evaluates access permissions and *Bong!* you got an access denied.

Use this config instead:
`<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /home/pi/repos
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repo"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/svn_access_control
  Require valid-user
 </Location>`

Comment: The problem with this configuration is anonymous users won't be able to read other repositories (as they are prompted to log in)